# Why the complexity of occurency in suffix tree is O(mn)?

Tags: algorithm

Based on this http://www.itu.dk/courses/AVA/E2005/StringIndexing.pdf
on page 12/36

Given a string **T[1...n]**, we build a suffix tree. The search pattern is **P[1...m]**.

```
• Preprocessing: O(n^2)
• Space: O(n^2)
• Occur(P in suffix tree): O(n*m) <===== why?
• Member is: O(m)
```

Comment: Where in that document does it say finding the occurrences is O(mn) time?  From what I read it says it's O(m+z) where z is the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Occur(...) operation in the material you refer to is not about searching for P from the suffix tree, but about finding longest matches (i.e. find the longest substring of P that occurs in the search tree) and report the corresponding leaves. It is worst case O(nm) operation because you need to take every suffix of P (that's O(m)) and possibly report O(n) leaves every time.